# C++ Doubly LinkedList in template

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

ListNode Code :

```
template <typename T>
struct ListNode {
public:
    T data;
    ListNode *prev, *next;
    ListNode() {
        prev = nullptr;
        next = nullptr;
    }
    ListNode(T Data, ListNode *Prev, ListNode *Next) {
        data = Data;
        prev = Prev;
        next = Next;
    }
};
```

Doubly LinkedList Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class List {
protected:
        ListNode<T> *head, *tail;
public:
        List<T>() {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }
        ~List<T>() {
            while (head != NULL) {
                pop_front();
            }
        }
        bool empty() const {
            if (head == NULL)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        void push_front(T data) {
            if (head != NULL) {
                head = new ListNode<T>(data, NULL, head);
                head -> next -> prev = head;
            }
            else {
                head = new ListNode<T>(data, NULL, NULL);
                tail = head; 
            }       
        }
        void push_back(T data) {
            if (tail != NULL) {
                tail = new ListNode<T>(data, tail, NULL);
                tail -> prev -> next = tail;
            }
            else {
                tail = new ListNode<T>(data, NULL, NULL);   
                head = tail;
            }  
        }
        void pop_front() {
            if (head != NULL) {
                ListNode<T> *temp = head;
                head = head -> next;
                delete temp;
            }
            else
                throw out_of_range("This list is empty.");
        }
        void pop_back() {
            if (tail != NULL) {
                ListNode<T> *temp = tail;
                tail = tail -> prev;
                delete temp;
            }
            else
                throw out_of_range("This list is empty.");
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const List<T>& list) {
            out << list.head -> data;
            ListNode<T> *temp = list.head -> next;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                out <<  ", " << temp -> data;
                temp = temp -> next;
            }
            return out; 
    } 
};
```

The Doubly LinkedList need to do push_front, push_back, pop_front, pop_back, pop_front, pop_back and bool empty.

outstream needs to use ", " to separate the data

I sent it to the online judge, but I got the runtime error.

I don't what's wrong in this code.

How to make it correct?

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: did you run your code with debuger?

Comment: After creating a new head or tail you have UB by accessing ->next->prev

Answer (score 0):

your problame was in the `pop_back()` function.

```
void pop_back() {
    if (tail != NULL) {
        ListNode<T> *temp = tail;
        tail = tail -> prev;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
        throw out_of_range("This list is empty.");
    }
```

you set the tail as the new tail but you forgat to update the new `tail->next` to `nullptr` so it was still pointing to the `old` tail you free in the line `delete temp;` all you need to do is to add this line `tail->prev->next = nullptr;` after the  `ListNode<T> *temp = tail;`.

so it will look like this:

```
void pop_back() {
    if (tail != NULL) {
        ListNode<T> * temp = tail;
        tail->prev->next = nullptr;
        tail = tail->prev;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
        throw out_of_range("This list is empty.");
    }
also as a
```

side note if you are using c++ 11 and above you can use the `auto` keyword and it will save you the `ListNode<T>` instead to will be `auto*` you can also keep the `*` and stay with `auto` but it more readable for my opinion to add the `*` so it will be clear that it a pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm  where? in the OP or in my answer?